# The Python executable is not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, path, command-prompt

I recently installed Python 3.6.3 on my device. When I type `python` in my [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) window, it gives me this error. I do have the PATH in the environment variables. [Path Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h31F.png). This should normally fix it, but `python` is still not recognized.

Comment: "I do have the PATH in the environment variables." It needs to be **before** the Microsoft Apps path, not after, because the path is searched **in order**. Otherwise, this is the same problem as when the PATH hasn't been set, so this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The path to the Python executable needs to be in the *System* PATH variable.  Note this is not the *User* PATH variable.

The OP had Python 3.6.3 installed in `C:\Python\Python36-32`, however a common default location for installation is in the users `AppData\Local\Programs\` folder.  This post will assume a Python 3.10 installation in this location.  Please adjust as needed for your current Python version and path.

You can confirm the path from the command prompt by checking the Python executable directly from the folder.

```
cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310
python --version
```

This should print the Python interpreter version.  For example, `Python 3.10.4`.

Add the following entries to the System PATH:

- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310` for the python executable
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` for tools such as `pip`

After adding the path to the System PATH variable, make sure you close and reopen any command prompts, so they use the updated PATH.

Comment: Thank You. How do you change the path from USER to System?

Comment: In your screenshot, you see an `Edit environment variable` window.  Behind that in the screenshot is the `Environment Variables` window which is divided into two sections.  The top section is the `User` section.  The bottom section is the `System` section.  Edit the `PATH` variable in the `System` section.

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem, due to a stupid decision from Microsoft.

I had another line in my system path variable:
`C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

And Windows 10 put a `python.exe` file there that only redirected me to the Python page of the Microsoft Store:

[image]

Since this line was above my true Python path, typing `python` in the cmd prompt opened the Microsoft Store...

**Solution:**

Type `App execution aliases` in the Windows 10 search bar, and then uncheck the aliases for `python.exe` and `python3.exe`. More information is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor).

Comment: Just tested the alias settings - no effect in Win11 Pro 22000.708 - gets forcefully re-enabled the same nanosecond you turn it off (both python.exe and python3.exe, but not any others). Works on Win10 Pro without issue, even without Python installed at all.

Comment: My exact same problem. I was going nuts trying to figure it out, thanks for posting it. Note, for me only this worked, not changing path priorities or moving paths around as others have suggested.

Comment: @afk5min I had the same problem on Win10. Turns out you need to close all the apps and programs that use Python. For me it was PyCharm. After that, re-enabling went away

Answer (score 11):

If it is still not working, as mentioned in the previous answers, then simply ***move up*** the path, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Image here]

Comment: I moved the system path (not user path) to the top and it worked.

Comment: thank you, that's correct the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

You get this error, because the **python.exe** path has not been added to the *System* environment variable. To do that, simply:

1. go to the path `C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` which contains **python.exe**
2. copy the path and open *System* environment variables and in the variable section look for variable called *Path*. If not, create a new variable with *Variable Name* as **Path** and value as the copied path

   [image]
3. Once you do that, close the window and simply open *cmd*. Type `python` and you should get something like this:

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to install the new Python version, `python-3.9.6`, then click the checkbox of **Add Python 3.9 to PATH**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the path doesn't exist in environment variables.

To fix this:

1. Rerun the installer
2. Choose <kbd>Modify</kbd>
3. In optional feature click "Next"
4. In advanced option tick the "Add Python to environment variables"
5. Install

Answer (score 2):

All the answers on Stack Overflow_ about it were obsolete, so I  decided to add this. The *path* variable that needs to be added is,

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
```

Note that everyone may have a different *Username*.

Comment: This depends on the location the user chooses to install python.  The accepted answer used the OPs install location.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Turns out the problem was related to a system vs user path.

Comment: This answer helped me; I had unknowingly installed python in this directory instead of the usual directory

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with the command prompt and if you are facing the issue even after adding the Python path to system variable PATH:

Remember to restart the command prompt (cmde.exe).

Answer (score 1):

I too was struggling with this issue, and everything was configured correctly. I installed and setup my system path variables as one would. And everything was fine. Then upon reboot windows would not recognize 'python' as a command as if it were unaware of the path variable. Double checked to confirm everything was still setup correctly (it was).

It only started to work again after I manually browsed to the directory in which python.exe existed, and ran 'python'. After that windows seemed to recognize my path variable and I could call 'python' from where ever need be. Very odd. Figured I'd share in case someone else runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6, there are actually two path entries. Also, it's best to use the %USERPROFILE% rather than hard coding it.

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

Comment: %USERPROFILE% only applies if that's where you are installing.  This would not work for custom paths.  The OP had python installed in c:\Python\Python36-32

Comment: Guys I still cannot get this to install on my new W10 Pro -- will recognize a (broken) pip, not python.  I hate Windows.