# Python not recognized in CMD under a specific folder

Tags: python

When I run `python` in cmd from a specific folder, it is giving the following error:

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

but when I run python from `C:\Users\iampr` then it is able to be recognized. Why is this the case?

Comment: Is "C:\Users\iampr>" in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: See [How to add Python to Path](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows). If you are ready to, just re-install Python and check the "Add Python to PATH" option in the setup EXE while installing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python is not recognized windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539201/python-is-not-recognized-windows-10)

Comment: also take look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for better understanding of path and environment variables in general

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall python and enable this option when prompted. Good day !

[Python Installation Wizard Option to add python to PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMtC9.png)