# The system cannot find the file C:

Tags: python, cmd

[image]

Hi Everybody,
I am having a problem with `cmd` when I am trying to run my python code in cmd. It says:-

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Darudul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe.
```

Please help me with this who knows the solution

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you look into [App Execution Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61958044/6273251)?

Comment: Does that executable file exist at that location? Has that command been added to your environment variables?

Comment: One of these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539201/python-is-not-recognized-windows-10, I'm guessing you installed python by the windows store? Might try uninstalling it from the store and installing the exe from the python site: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Check this https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor

Answer (score 0):

If Python is installed on your C drive, you may need to add it to PATH.
Search and open system properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.
From there, click on the one called Path, click Edit, then hit New and put C:\path\to\your\python\Python3xx

For reference, I installed python in the default location which was C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

If you cannot find your python, try installing a new version. The new versions of the python installer have an option to add it to path, make sure you check that.

Comment: python downloads can be found [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: this is also latest version because today only I installed

Comment: still, I couldn't solve this, already I have spent 4.30 hours.